# Set element's size to largest square to fit within container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Essentially, if its container's dimensions are m x n, I want to set an element's dimensions to min(m,n) x min(m,n).

I've seen similar questions asked here before, but the answers all seemed to assume that the container's width would be greater than its height - something that is not guaranteed in my scenario.

At the moment I'm calculating it with JavaScript, but I'd prefer a pure CSS solution. I originally thought I could do something with media queries using the "orientation" property, but I think media queries can only refer to overall viewport, and not a specific element? So that wouldn't work.

Is this possible in pure CSS?

Comment: Nope...not with CSS. There are no "element queries" nor is their "min of two values". You're stuck with JS I'm afraid.

Comment: What about [fit-content](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content) property?